# Spring Boot work with Spring Loaded and Gradle

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot, spring-loaded

I am trying to get a simple Spring-Boot application to work with Spring Loaded and Gradle without any success. I have tried the following:

1. Using Spring-Boot with the `bootRun` task simply reloads static resources just fine with a simple F5 in the browser
2. If I use `bootRun` again and change a class through a text editor and the use `compileJava` it doesnt work.
3. If I run it with `IntelliJ Application` make a change in an existing controller and use the IntelliJ `make` it works only for existing methods. Doesnt update new methods, change of signatures etc.
4. Using IntelliJ with VM argument:

   -javaagent:C:\Users\myuser\.m2\repository\org\springframework\springloaded\1.2.1.RELEASE\springloaded-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar -noverify

Still does nothing.

Ideally, I would like to perform the process through using Gradle only - so I'm IDE independent

Please have a look at the Github project so you can see my sample code:
[Sample Project](https://github.com/cgeo7/springboot-springloaded)

Just perform any changes in the `DemoController`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the trick was to use the task `build bootRun` instead of a simple 'bootRun`.

This is a Gradle build file that also uses the watch plugin with incremental compiles when Java classes change:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.2.2.RELEASE'
        springLoadedVersion = "1.2.1.RELEASE"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.springframework:springloaded:${springLoadedVersion}")
        classpath 'com.bluepapa32:gradle-watch-plugin:0.1.5'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}

apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "spring-boot"
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'com.bluepapa32.watch'


mainClassName = "com.example.my.Application"

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    runtime("org.hsqldb:hsqldb")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { gradleVersion = '2.3' }

idea {
    module {
        inheritOutputDirs = false
        outputDir = new File("$buildDir/classes/main/")
    }
}

compileJava {
    //enable compilation in a separate daemon process
    options.fork = true
    //enable incremental compilation
    options.incremental = true
}

watch {
    java {
        files files('src/main/java')
        tasks 'compileJava'
    }
}
```